# Создание экземпляров класса с именами из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, list

Есть список списков:

```
[[name1, value1], [name2, value2], ...]
```

Нужно создавать экземпляры одного класса с именами name1, name2 и так далее, т.е. с именами, взятыми из list[1][1], list[2][1] и т.д.
Если экземпляры классов инициализировались вручную, то было бы так:

```
name1 = class(value1)
name2 = class(value2)
```

Но не представляю методы, которыми это можно реализовать.

**UPD1:**

Класс:

```
class func():
    def __init__(self, visibility, ftype, body):
    ...
```

Существующий список:

```
list = ['private', 'Void', 'SetupWheels', 'body']
```

Словарь:

```
func_list = {}
```

Надо сделать так:

```
for i, val in enumerate(c):
    *новый ключ в словаре, равный значению list[2]* = func(list[0], list[0], list[3])
```

Comment: Решение вам уже показали, а я хочу добавить, что лучше всё-таки не создавать много однотипных объектов в глобальной области видимости, а складывать их в словарь, где в качестве ключей использовать ваши имена из списка.

Comment: @Александр а в качестве значения по ключу будет что? Не совсем понял как это реализовать.

Comment: А в качестве значений - сами экземпляры. Вот такой словарь получится: `{name1: class(value1), name2: class(value2)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться явным добавлением переменной в необходимую область видимости. Например, для вашего случая пойдёт следующий код:

```
for name, val in your_list:
    globals()[name] = your_class(val)
```

Теперь можно обращаться к переменным с именами `name1, name2, ...` .