# Создание объектов в Python прогрммой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как заставить программу генерировать объекты одного класса с разными именами(объект a1, a2, a3 и т.д)
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Типа такого `open("a.py", 'w', encoding="utf-8").write("class A:\n    def say(self):print('Hello, A!')\n\nA().say()")`?

Comment: Используйте список вместо кучи однотипных имен переменных.

Comment: Здравствуйте, скажите ответ nomnoms12 вам подходит?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание экземпляров класса с именами из списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669294/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `exec`, которая исполняет произвольный код.

***Пример:***

```py
class Spam:
    pass


names = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
for name in names:
    exec(f'{name} = Spam()')

print(a1, a2, a3)
```

***stdout (частично):***

```py
<__main__.Spam object...> <__main__.Spam object...> <__main__.Spam object...>
```

*Примечание:*
Функция `exec` опасна и потенциально приводит к уязвимости исполнения произвольного кода. Используйте её, только если уверены в безопасности вводимых данных.